# Round to keys in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, rounding

The purpose of the below code is to return minimum pipe slopes for inputted diameters. The code returns an error if the DIA input (in meters) is not within the key values.

```
D_MINSLOPE = {100:60, 150:100, 225:300, 300:400, 375:550, 450:700, 525:750, 600:900, 675:1050, 750:1200, 825:1380, 900:1600, 1050:2000, 1200:2400, 1350:2800, 1500:3250, 1650:3700, 1800:4200}

def minslope(DIA):
    DIA_mm = round(DIA * 1000)
    Slope = 1/D_MINSLOPE[DIA_mm]
    return Slope
```

I am currently going to resolve the issue with 'try/except' 'if/elif' to round up through the different bases (50, 75, 150) as per [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2272149/9617655).

Is there a more pythonic way to round to the key values?

I note the question is similar to the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33450235/9617655) which is in regards to arrays.

Comment: If the DIA_mm is not in your list, do you want the closest value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, Following example from related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141207/5916727), you can search for closest `key` in the dictionary. For e.g. if you want to search for `500`:

`min(D_MINSLOPE, key=lambda x:abs(x-500))`

will return `525` which is the closest value in the keys of `dictionary`.

So, you can try changing function as:

```
def minslope(DIA):
    # convert Diameter (m) to Diameter (mm)
    DIA_mm = DIA * 1000        
    # get closest value
    DIA_cv = min(D_MINSLOPE, key=lambda x:abs(x-DIA_mm))   
    Slope = 1/D_MINSLOPE[DIA_cv]
    return Slope
```

Comment: there is no need of `.keys()`

Comment: I was to publish that same answer ;)

Comment: At this point though, you probably shouldn't be using a dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure, what would you suggest?

Comment: A list of tuples would work just as well (likely faster). If you are iterating over every key in a dictionary to retrieve a value, that defeats the entire purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same approach as above, but this was my take on the question. I recreated the dictionary of keys as intervals, and if `DIA` falls in that interval it would return that value, rather than the use of the closest.

**Also you might want to change 1 to 1.0, to make sure that your value returns a floating number instead of an integer. (I'm assuming that is what you are after).**

```
D_MINSLOPE = {100:60, 150:100, 225:300, 300:400, 375:550, 450:700, 525:750,
              600:900, 675:1050, 750:1200, 825:1380, 900:1600, 1050:2000,
              1200:2400, 1350:2800, 1500:3250, 1650:3700, 1800:4200}


def change_dict(dictionary):
    """
    Changes the dictionary to contain intervals as keys

    Returns:
        {(1651, 1800): 4200, (301, 375): 550,
         (1201, 1350): 2800, (451, 525): 750,
         (751, 825): 1380, (526, 600): 900,
         (1, 100): 60, (676, 750): 1200,
         (1051, 1200): 2400, (1351, 1500): 3250,
         (826, 900): 1600, (901, 1050): 2000,
         (376, 450): 700, (151, 225): 300,
         (101, 150): 100, (1501, 1650): 3700,
         (601, 675): 1050, (226, 300): 400}
    """
    new_dict = {}
    temp = [0] + sorted(D_MINSLOPE.keys())
    i = 0
    while i < len(D_MINSLOPE.keys()):
        key = temp[i+1]; value = D_MINSLOPE[key]
        new_key = (temp[i] + 1, temp[i+1])
        new_dict[new_key] = value
        i += 1
    return new_dict


def minslope(DIA):
    DIA_mm = round(DIA * 1000)
    D_MINSLOPE_2 = change_dict(D_MINSLOPE)    # Change dictionary keys

    # Find the key in which DIA_mm falls under
    key = None
    for i in D_MINSLOPE_2:
        if (i[0] <= DIA) and (i[1] >= DIA):
            key = i
            break

    # Change 1 to 1.0, as it needs to be a float number to output decimals
    # otherwise it would probably output 0 as an integer.
    return 1.0/D_MINSLOPE_2[key]
```